# "adb pull" returns empty file in Bash script

Tags: android, bash, file, adb, pull

I am writing a script to take a heap dump on android, pull it to my computer, and optionally convert it to standard hprof. The primary commands used are:

```
adb shell "am dumpheap ${PROCESS} /data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof"
adb pull "/data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof"
adb shell "rm /data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof"
```

When I execute the lines one by one in terminal, everything works fine. However, when I run those commands in the bash script, adb pull grabs an empty file.

When run in terminal, adb pull takes quite a long time and reports progress percentage, but when run in the bash script, it just immediately says

```
"/data/local/tmp/heapdump-05_22_2017_1807-unconverted.hprof: 1 file pulled"
```

I looked through all the adb pull/push posts I could find to try to figure this out but nothing worked or really applied. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it was the dumpheap call that wasn't completing since it runs as a daemon and adb pull was actually correct in pulling an empty file.

I solved this by adding a wait function that waited until the file on the device was complete to proceed:

```
waitForFile() {
    # wait for file to stabalize at a size above 0
    local lastSize=0
    local matchCount=0
    while [ ${matchCount} -lt 3 ] ;
    do
        if [[ ${lastSize} -gt 0 && $(fileSize) = ${lastSize} ]] ;
            then
            let "matchCount+=1"
            echo "match ${matchCount}"
        else
            matchCount=0
            lastSize=$(fileSize)
            echo "Dumping file...current size = ${lastSize}"
        fi
        sleep 0.5
    done
    echo "Heap Dump Complete, file size = ${lastSize}"
}

fileSize() {
    local size=$(echo $(adb shell "ls -s /data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof") | cut -f1 -d' ')
    echo $size
}

adb shell "am dumpheap ${PROCESS} /data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof"
waitForFile
adb pull "/data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof"
adb shell "rm /data/local/tmp/${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof"
```

For anyone reading who wants to use this to get a standard hprof, you can add the following line at the end:

```
hprof-conv -z ${FILENAME}-unconverted.hprof ${FILENAME}-standard.hprof
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a short sleep (i.e. sleep 5) after you call dumpheap and before you call abd pull (ugly but fast solution).
2. you can store the pid of the dumpheap process and wait for it to end before calling adb pull.
   good luck.

Comment: Just saw this, thanks for your response! I added a more reliable (but still a bit ugly) wait function similar to your suggestion in 1. I don't think 2 will work unfortunately because dumpheap daemonizes itself.